# Socket.IO video client

Tags: html, node.js, socket.io

hi i am attempting to make a syncing video client as a hobby, lets not get to deep into making the client actually work because i kind of want to figure that out myself, how ever you might be able to help me out with my current issue.

ok, i started with the "hello world" intro on socket.io's website as a way to learn how to pass messages, there by i handled how users connect and how they are served the HTML the same wa. users connect to the index.js and it hands them the HTML. all the html is doing is showing them the videos and listening for if the user pauses.

here is the JS

```
    var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('message', function(msg){
    io.emit('message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});



  here is the html



    <!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<center> <p><video src="test.mp4" controls></video></p> </center>

<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
  var video = $_("video");

  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
         socket.emit('message', "pause");
    }, true);


</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

if i connect to the target specified by the js the video is not found. if i simply open the HTML in a browser the video is found fine

where do i have to put the video for the js to find it? do i have to specify full path?

Comment: If you're just toying with all this, I'll suggest WebRTC along with websockets for media streaming. It's made specifically for that purpose. Leave sockets for centralized message handling or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing something to serve your static files. Express has a built-in [`express.static()`](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.built-in) middleware you can use for this purpose. Typically you place this middleware near the top of your stack so that requests for static files can be served immediately without having to traverse the list of other middleware and/or routes.